# rails 4: problems with inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, model

I probably didn't understand STI or whatever inheritance of rails :)

I need to implement a design where I have a form; on upload I submit, but if the user is not logged in, she needs to login via openid (only access supported). Thus this implies a redirect, and the best thing I could come up with so far is to temporarily save the data, and on successful login actually create the real object. I wanted to have two separate tables for the objects; the `Site` object is the one to be created, the `Sitetmp` is the temporary store, and it has an additional field called nonce; (on successful login, the nonce will be compared, and if ok, the `Sitetmp` instance deleted and a new `Site` one created)

The DB:

```
#schema.rb
 create_table "sites", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "date"
    t.text     "description"
    t.float    "lat"
    t.float    "lon"
    t.date     "updated"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "sitetmps", force: true do |t|
    t.string "nonce"
    t.string "name"
    t.date   "date"
    t.text   "description"
  end
```

The Subclass:

```
#app/models/sitetmp.rb
class Sitetmp < Site
  attr_accessor :nonce
end
```

The Superclass:

```
#app/models/site.rb
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  validates :date, :presence => true

  has_many :images, :inverse_of => :site
end
```

It seemed to be all set, but when I actually want to access the temporary object on successful login, it tells me

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: sites.nonce: SELECT "sites".* FROM "sites" WHERE "sites"."nonce" = '059253928646750523787961570357' LIMIT 1
```

The code in the controller causing this is:

```
if nonce 
          @tmp = Sitetmp.find_by nonce: nonce
```

Clearly I am trying to access the `Sitetmp` instance by its `nonce` attribute, but `rails` is resolving to actually access the `Site` class - which doesn't have a `nonce` attribute.

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly find the `Sitetmp` object by `nonce` in order to create a valid `Site` object from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, `ActiveRecord::Base` has a `table_name` method. If you inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, the subclass (`Site`), through some rails magic, has the `table_name` set to the underscored lowercased version of itself.

Then inheriting from the `Site` class, `Sitetmp` does not get the advantage of having the `table_name` set.

You may be able to fix this by setting this:

```
#app/models/sitetmp.rb
class Sitetmp < Site
  # Set custom table name
  table_name "sitetmp"
  attr_accessor :nonce
end
```

I don't know if this would have an impact on the `table_name` of the `Site` class, so you may just have to create a standalone `Sitetmp` model to work from.

Alternatively, you could load the values into the `session` - [see here for more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session)

Comment: Actually, I accepted your response for the suggestion to create a standalone Sitetmp class, which I had done already :)